# Problem to obtain an array of Boolean values

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have to create a function that analyzes a list. In an array, if the element of this list is larger than 0, it has to return True otherwise False. This is what I’ve written. We saw that if we simply compare two arrays, it automatically returns an array of Boolean values.

```py
import numpy as np
def adjacency(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    pool = np.full_like(arr, 0)
    arr > pool
```

However here, they give me the error: « Your function does not return a numpy array »
Thus I tried to write another code:

```
import numpy as np

def adjacency(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    for x in arr:
        if np.any(x == 0):
            x = False
        if np.any(x > 0):
            x = True
```

But it does say the same thing as above...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done with your code. You want like this, right?

```
import numpy as np

def adjacency(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    print(arr)
    new_arr = []
    for x in arr:
        if np.any(x <= 0):
            x = False
            new_arr.append(x)
        else:
            x = True
            new_arr.append(x)
    arr1 = np.array(new_arr)
    print(arr1)
    return new_arr

print(adjacency([1,-2,3,4,0,-10]))
```

Output:

```
[  1  -2   3   4   0 -10]
[ True False  True  True False False]
[True, False, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of creating a new list. However, it does not give me the right result. With your list it gives me one list, only with the False Boolean values. And when i try with a nested list (lists contained in a list), it gives me only the first list with the false values. The function should give us an array at the end, so i think we have to return the array and not the list at end. But there is a problem with the for loop, because we only obtain on list with only false values...

Answer (score 0):

The bigger than/equals/smaller than signs must be written like this to work.
Try this

```
def adjacency(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    out = []
    for x in arr:
        if np.any(x <= 0):
            x = False
            out.append(x)
        elif np.any(x >> 0):
            x = True
            out.append(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of creating a new list. However, it does not give me the right result. With your list it gives me one list, only with the False Boolean values. And when i try with a nested list (lists contained in a list), it gives me only the first list with the false values. The function should give us an array at the end, so i think we have to return the array and not the list at end. But there is a problem with the for loop, because we only obtain on list with only false values...